# Use Prolog to definition the departments and employees relationship

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I'm working my way through an old exam and trying to check my work. I've attached images but the text is as quoted below:

> We want to extend a program for handling the staff of a company.
>
> For each department there is a fact `department(Id, Manager, Groups)` that defines the name of the department, `Id`, the name of its manager, `Manager`, and a list of working groups or other departments which constitute the department, `Groups`.
>
> For each working group there is a fact, `group(Id, Leader, Participant)`, that defines `Id`, a unique name for the group, `Leader`, a manager or leader of the group, and a list, `Participant`, containing the names of the members of the group.
>
> Individuals can be members of one or more working groups, or "just" managers. The same person can be leader or manager for multiple groups/departments. Leaders are considered to be part of the working group they lead, while managers higher up in the hierarchy are not automatically members in any working group.
>
> E.g. the database of the program can look like this:
>
> ```
>    department( management, knut_billkvist, [administration, factory] ).
>    department( administration, lisa_larsson, [economy, staff] ).
>    department( economy, ahmed_hassan, [billing, budget, project_office] ).
>    department( staff, jenny_bengtsson, [recruitment, health, salaries] ).
>    department( factory, rune_viking, [assembly, testing] ).
>
>    group( billing, lotta_persson, [anna_nilsson,arne_johnsson] ).
>    group( budget, lena_levin, [kurt_allgen, mona_malm] ).
>    group( project_office, ahmed_hassan, [kurt_allgen, anna_nilsson] ).
>    group( recruitment, lill_nilsson, [annie_cedrell, jonna_spjuth] ).
>    group( salaries, bengt_karlsson, [gullbritt_svensson, siri_hallin] ).
>    group( assembly, rune_runesson, [johnny_kraft] ).
>    group( testing, allan_snygg, [edvin_karlsson, mohammed_tayed] ).
> ```
>
> Define these predicates!
>
> - A predicate `coworker(Name, Department, Group)` which is true if a person, `Name`, belongs to a certain department, `Department`, and a certain working group, `Group`, (use `none` if the person doesn't belong to any working group).
> - A predicate `leader(Name, GroupId)` that is true if a person, `Name`, is a leader of a certain working group `GroupId`.
> - A predicate `manager(Name, Id)` that is true if a person is a manager for a certain department, `Id` or ledaer of a working group with the name `Id`.
>
> Please consider that individuals can often be members of working groups directly, and they can also be implicit members of departments on several levels!

My code is as follows:

```
coworker(Name,Department,Group):-
    begot(Name,department(ID,Name,group),Group).

leader(Name,GroupID):-
    bagof(Name,Group(ID,Name,Participants),GroupId).

manager(Name,ID):-
    setof (Name,Department(ID,Name,Groups),ID)setof (Name,Group(Id,names,participants),GroupId).
```

I have modified my code following the suggestions below into this:

```
cowoker(Name,Department,Group) :-
   group(Group,Name,Manager).

leader(Name,GroupID) :-
   Group(_,Name,GroupID).

manager(Name,ID) :-
   department(_,Name,ID),
   Group(_,Name,GroupId).
```

Comment: Please read the online help for how to ask a good question.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear: come up with the code for the three predicates in the second scanned image. I don't understand why it has been put on hold.

Comment: What book is this from, by the way?

Comment: @DanielLyons. A big edit, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have some confusion about what you can use for variables or identifiers in Prolog. Every variable **must** begin with an uppercase letter, and every identifier **must not** begin with one. So the code `Group(Id,Name,Participants)` is wrong, because `Group` begins with an uppercase letter, and `department(Id,Name,group)` is wrong, because `group` should be capitalized. On top of that, this line is just zany: `setof (Name,Department(ID,Name,Groups),ID)setof ...`

I don't think you actually need `setof/3` or `bagof/3` or `findall/3` to answer *any* of these questions. I'll give you one of them, because I can tell this is homework, but it should be sufficient for you to see how to approach the problem.

```
leader(Name, GroupId) :- 
    group(GroupId, Name, _).
```

You're programming with relations here. The relationship between `leader(Name, Group)` is that there is some group `Group` and `Name` is the leader. This is what I have specified in my definition of `leader/2`. Notice that I didn't do anything with the list of people in the group. I don't need them for this task. This is just rearranging the data you already have! It doesn't have to be taxing.

The other two questions are almost as easy. Now try, and do not let yourself be confused by second-order predicates! I don't think you'll need them.

**Edit**: since this is not homework, let's look at how I would do the other two.

`coworker/3` is sort of misnamed; it doesn't tell you anything about a pair of workers, just what group and department each person is in. So the implementation will use `member/2` to enumerate people, like so:

```
coworker(Name, Department, Group) :-
    department(Department, _, Groups),
    member(Group, Groups),
    group(Group, _, People),
    member(Name, People).
```

This is actually only 1/3rd of the story. This case covers people at the bottom rung, but it won't get people who manage groups or who manage departments and thus exist above the whole group hierarchy, so we need two more rules:

```
 coworker(Name, Department, none) :-
      department(Department, Name, _).
 coworker(Name, Department, Group) :-
      department(Department, _, Groups),
      member(Group, Groups),
      group(Group, Name, _).
```

It feels like we could implement this with `manager/2` but `manager/2` discards the information about whether they manage a department or a group, so we can't use it to recover that information without redoing some work. So it's probably better to define it separately, although it will look like the second and third clauses of `coworker/3` repeated:

```
 manager(Name, Department) :-
      department(Department, Name, _).
 manager(Name, Group) :-
      department(Department, _, Groups),
      member(Group, Groups),
      group(Group, Name, _).
```

There you have it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for you comments, i will try use your idea by the way this is not about home work, assignment or academic work, this is my earlier exam,i just want sort out the answers.

Comment: Hi Daniel, here i did some modifies, could you help check whether correct ?cowoker(Name,Department,Group):-
group(Group,Name,Manager).

leader(Name,GroupID):-
Group(_,Name,GroupID).

manager(Name,ID):-
department(_,Name,ID),Group(_,Name,GroupId).